# "Undefined method `each' for :ole_object:Symbol

Tags: watir

Today i installed `Ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]` and i have the following problem. Was working fine with `Ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [i386-mswin32]`.  I searched in many forums and still could not find a soultion. Please help!

I am getting the error `Undefined method 'each' for :ole_object:Symbol (NoMethodError)` when clicking a button using the code below.

```
ie.frame(:id,"body").table(:id,"recordListButton_UserList_ctl00")[1][2].click_no_wait
```

This was working fine in ruby 1.8.6

Error:

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.4/lib/watir/locator.rb:11:in `normalize_specifiers!': undefined method `each' 
for :ole_object:Symbol (NoMethodError) 

from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.4/lib/watir/locator.rb:43:in `set_specifier' 
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.4/lib/watir/container.rb:109:in `tagged_element_locator' 
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.4/lib/watir/element.rb:36:in `locate' 
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.4/lib/watir/table.rb:249:in `locate' 
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.4/lib/watir/element.rb:75:in `assert_exists' 
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.4/lib/watir/table.rb:285:in `[]' 
from //coldstorage/intranet/QA/Automation/Clickability for Blank DB- New Look and Feel/Admin Tab/Click_User_page_CC.rb:75:in `<main>' 

>Exit code: 0
```

**Note:** when i try to do

```
ie.frame(:id,"body").table(:id,"recordListButton_UserList_ctl00").click_no_wait
```

in Watir 1.9.2 it is working. I don't understand why

```
table(:id,"recordListButton_UserList_ctl00")[1][2]
```

is causing the error. And the error is complaining about the method 'each' which i am not using anywhere in my script. Please help!

I have the following gems installed on my machine:

```
activesupport (2.3.9) 
builder (3.0.0) 
commonwatir (2.0.4, 2.0.3, 1.7.1, 1.6.7) 
ffi (1.0.9 x86-mingw32) 
firewatir (1.7.1, 1.6.7) 
hoe (2.12.3) 
minitest (1.6.0) 
nokogiri (1.5.0 x86-mingw32) 
rake (0.8.7) 
rautomation (0.6.3) 
rdoc (2.5.8) 
s4t-utils (1.0.4) 
user-choices (1.1.6.1) 
watir (2.0.4) 
win32-api (1.4.8 x86-mingw32) 
win32-process (0.6.5) 
windows-api (0.4.0) 
windows-pr (1.2.1) 
xml-simple (1.1.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error I see above seems to indicate you upgraded not only Ruby, but Watir as well since I see **2.0.4** as part of the path to the the watir files.

One of the major changes between watir 1.x and watir 2.x is the move from one based to zero based indexing.

Have you revised the index values in your code, or added the following to the top of your scripts to use the old 1 based indexing?

```
require "watir"; Watir.options[:zero_based_indexing] = false
```

It might be that the error is a result of trying to send watir looking after an element that simply is not there.. e.g. the third cell on a row of a table with only two columns.

If the link you are clicking is the first one in the table, that might explain why just using `.link` (which is the same as `.link(:index => 0)` ) is working correctly, but trying to address the item by row and cell is not.

Comment: You guys are awesome. It is the indexing problem. When i try table(:id,"recordListButton_UserList_ctl00")[0][1] it is working. I double checking it with other places in my application as well. When i reduce the index by one, my scripts are working. But i could not get "Watir.options[:zero_based_indexing] = false" working. Do i need to do something more to get this working? I included this line of code at the top of my script but it is not able to identify "table(:id,"recordListButton_UserList_ctl00")[1][2].click". It would be great if i can get this working. Thanks!

Comment: I found on this website (http://watir.com/2011/08/11/watir-2-0/) that the option "Watir.options[:zero_based_indexing] = false" will be removed in the future. Is it already removed? If yes, i will start making the index changes in my scritps. Thanks!

Comment: Well personally I'd make the changes anyway because then you have greater ability to perhaps be able to run those scripts under Watir-Webdriver to test against FireFox and Chrome

Comment: it would be a bit early for it to be removed, and I didn't notice anything about that in the change list  (you can see it from the github page for watir)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like ticket [WTR-459](http://jira.openqa.org/browse/WTR-459) (click_no_wait does not work with frames). But, as far as I can see, that ticket is fixed.